# Fix Right Border line for a row of table

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add border line with color white , but it appears to be a line that is incorrect when you closely observe the bottom edges of the white line. Can anyone help me on correcting this thin white line border . Have added fiddle [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qB9pm/)

```
<table border="1px" cellpadding="5px" cellspacing="0px" width="10%"><tbody><tr style="background-color:#3b72ab;cursor:pointer"> 
<td style="width:5px;background-color:#ad0303; border-right:solid 2px #ffffff;border-bottom:solid 2px #2b557f" width="0.5px">
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: the border-bottom's color is obviously set to a color other than the white, what is the exact problem you mean?

Comment: I put this fiddle together just to make it more readable.http://jsfiddle.net/qB9pm/3/ Can you give us more details on what you want? You aren't using this for layout are you? Could all be done in a div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add this styling to your table -- >

**CSS**

```
table{
   border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qB9pm/1/)

You can refer to this **[link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-collapse.asp)** for more info about `border-collapse`  .

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that there's still a thin black line next to your white border, that's because you have to remove all the other borders on the right from the elements `table`, `td` and `tr`.

You can solve it by adding this code to your css file, or you put it inline like you wish.

```
table, tr, td {
    border-right: 0px
}
```